# Failed to connect to the configuration Database

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, installation

I have fresh installation for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

SharePoint has been installed but once I run Configuration Wizard I get an error message:

> An exception of type system.InvalidOperationException was thrown. additional exception information: cannot start service SPADminV4 on computer

Any idea how we could pass this issue?

Comment: have u already checked this:
[blog by Amit Bhatia](https://bhatiaamit.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/psconfig-fails-system-invalidoperationexception-cannot-start-service-spadminv4-on-computer-after-cu-install/)

Comment: yes , still not working

Comment: Few Possible known things, One check whether the account you are performing is having Admin access on the local machine and then check the account you are using for configuration is having access to DB and have Db Admin access.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reason for this type of error.

- Make Sure Server connected to Internet
- SharePoint admin service also perform the CRL checks, may be better idea to fix those checks. [follow this blog](http://olorunosebijames3.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepoint-2010-error-cannot-start.html)
- Sometime running the command line tool fix it... run [psconfig to create the config db](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/psconfig-commands1).`psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -create -server <SQL Server name> -database <database name> -user <AD user account> -password <AD user password>`